# Как объединить массивы дат?

Tags: php, ооп

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть такой метод который должен объединять массивы дат в объекте, но я не пойму что туда необходимо дописать... в метод add прилетают обычные массивы дат

```html
public function add(Days $days): Days
    {

        
    }
```

Метод который формирует массивы дат
public function getVacationDates(User $user): Days
    {
        $allVacationDays = new Days([]);

```
    foreach ($user->getVacation() as $vacation) {

        $vacationDays = Days::fromRange($vacation->getStartVacation(), $vacation->getEndVacation());
        $allVacationDays->add($vacationDays);
    }

    return $allVacationDays;
}
```

Класс

```html
class Days
{
    private $rangeDays;

    public function __construct(array $rangeDays)
    {
        $this->rangeDays = $rangeDays;
    }

    public function remove(array $arr): Days
    {

        return new Days(array_diff($this->rangeDays, $arr));
    }

    public function add(Days $days): Days
    {

       
    }

    public static function fromRange($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $vacationsDate = [];

        $start = new Carbon($startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
        $end = new Carbon($endDate->format('Y-m-d'));

        while ($start->lte($end)) {
            $vacationsDate[] = $start->toDateString();
            $start->addDay();
        }

        return new self($vacationsDate);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму: метод add() описан:

```
public function add(Days $days): Days
{
    return new Days(array_merge($this->rangeDays, $days));
}
```

в нем к массив $days дополняется датой из $this->rangeDays. Если Вам необходимо дополнить массив $days другим массивом - просто замените $this->rangeDays на тот другой массив.

Comment: извиняюсь,  забыл удалить внутренности метода add. Это я так пробовал, на так не сработало.. в метод add приходит каждый раз массив дат, нужно чтобы эти массивы скапливались, пока foreach не закончится

Answer (score 0):

Тогда смею предположить, что в метод необходимо передать именно массив дат:

```
public function add(array $new_arr_days): void
{
    $this->rangeDays = array_merge($this->rangeDays, $new_arr_days);
}
```